# URL forwarding and header/content modification

Tags: java, http, url, forwarding

Say there is an incoming HTTP `POST` request to `/first/path`.

Is there any sample Java code that adds new `Header1` and forward this `POST` to `/second/path.`

This is a server side forwarding using `RequestDispatcher` service within Spring filter. This has to be URL forwarding and not just chaining the filters.

Answer (score 0):

This post is perfect for what you are looking for.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4206094/1354978

With editable headers.

Comment: I was looking for specific example to perform URL Forwarding within the server.

Comment: So here is the http server part. So now you have all the parts. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717294/create-a-simple-http-server-with-java