# How to create a light-weight server like nginx from scratch?

Tags: nginx

Okay, I know it's a stupid question, but I really want to know, I'm that damn kid who breaks up every toy just to see how it works, but unfortunately I can't break nginx. Anyway I'm using Windows, I know Java, Python, PHP and a few more languages, but I have no idea how a server is built.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off:

[Create a simple HTTP server with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717294/create-a-simple-http-server-with-java)

Try this for a simple python server:

http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-really-simple-http-server-python

Here's a pretty simple java web server:

http://cs.au.dk/~amoeller/WWW/javaweb/server.html

Comment: Thank you buddy, I'm going to check it out.

Comment: There were also about a hundred good links that pop up if you google "simple [insert programming language here] web server". Just a heads up.