# Educational socket application with Java and HTML

Tags: javascript, java, html, sockets

I am teaching a Java course. Instead of teaching the Java GUI libraries (awt or swing), I want to teach my students to use HTML for GUI, and use Java only in the server side. So, I want to build a Java server and an  HTML page that connect to each other using sockets. I want to use only raw Java, so that my students do not have to install third-party libraries. So far, I built the following Java server, which just accepts strings and reverses them:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ReversingServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int port = 8005;
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        while (true) {
            final Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter writer    = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

            String input = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println("input="+input);
            String output = (input==null? 
                    null: 
                    new StringBuilder(input).reverse().toString()); 
            writer.println("The reverse of "+input+" is ... ");
            writer.println("... "+output+"!");
            writer.close();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this application, I can do "telnet localhost 8005" and send a string such as "abc" and get the response "the reverse of abc is cba".

I also started building the HTML GUI:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test the Reversing Server</title>
</head>

<body>
<div>
Enter a string to reverse:
<input name="input"></input>
<input type="submit"></input>
</div>

<div id='response' style='border:solid 1pt black'>
&nbsp;
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

But here I am stuck - how do I make the HTML page connect to the Java server?

Comment: HTML communicates over the HTTProtocol  - If it were so easier to write your own web server there would be no need for Tomcat and others

Comment: see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/create-a-java-web-application-using-embedded-tomcat

Comment: @ScaryWombat this tutorial requires knowledge of Maven, which is beyond the current knowledge of my students. Isn't there a simpler solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717294/create-a-simple-http-server-with-java ?

Comment: @RC the answers there are over 7 years old, do not handle sockets, and do not contain code for connecting from HTML...

Comment: if the question is how to make a web server in java it still apply. If the question is how to do the "html" part, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407778/connecting-to-tcp-socket-from-browser-using-javascript. My opinion is that we have an X/Y problem here, the usual way to do this is to have an http server and use a standard html form

Comment: @RC this looks more related. The answers are from 2013, and they say that it is impossible to connect from HTML to raw TCP sockets. Is this still impossible in 2017?

Comment: I don't know. I added the javascript tag because this is more javascript than java